# issue with pre populating items in a multi select menu

Tags: jquery

I have a multi select menu item on an edit page to show selected documents that are required for a check list item. I use the code below to set the attr for each option that needs to be selected.

```
jQuery("#e_docs_jobCheckList_0 option[value=" + tmpId + "]").attr("selected", true);
```

Whilst the code above shows the correct selected items visually, it does not add the "selected=selected" attribute to each option.

This is an issue because I then use a multi-select javascript library that does not pick up the selected options because it cannot see any that have "selected=selected".

I have tried various different ways to add the attr but none add the code.

Any ideas what could cause this, have found nothing on Google to suggest why?

This image hopefully explains it better

[image]

Comment: show what console says for `jQuery("#e_docs_jobCheckList_0 option[value=" + tmpId + "]").length` ?

Comment: it comes back as 1

Comment: Your code, *as provided* (and assuming the selector is correct, as confirmed above), [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/c2r3mxp5/).   It's more likely the way you're reading it / the unnamed library or just an order.   Try `$(..).attr("selected", true).change()`

Comment: interesting....running this code 

`jQuery("#e_docs_jobCheckList_0 option[value=" + tmpId + "]").attr("selected", "1");
jQuery("#e_docs_jobCheckList_0 option[value=" + tmpId + "]").attr("id", tmpId);`

produces the following

`<option value="1" id="1">test doc1</option>`

Comment: replace attr by prop like - $('#element').prop('selected', true);

Comment: jQuery(...).prop is not a function - i think there is a js conflict somewhere